# cp command recursively writes directories

Tags: bash, cp

I have a standard .ssh directory in my user home dir.

I have this command:

```
cp -rf "$HOME/.ssh" "ssh/prod"
```

I get this situation:

[image: directory tree]

does anyone know why it's recursively writing out subfolders in the destination?

Comment: did you make a symlink to "ssh/prod" inside "$HOME/.ssh", or make a symlink?

Comment: What are the contents of `$HOME/.ssh`?

Answer (score 2):

Well the reason it is recursively writing out subfolders is because you gave it the recursive option. '-r'

"cp -rf" is equal to "copy -recursive -force"